# How to Iterate with python dataframe

Tags: pandas, loops, iterator

I'm trying to iterate in my data frame and create a column with the result

import pandas as pd

```
data = {'Name': ['Mary', 'Jose', 'John', 'Marc', 'Ruth','Rachel'],
        'Grades': [10, 8, 8, 5, 7,4],
        'Gender':['Female','Male','Male','Male','Female','Female']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

values = []
for x in df.iteritems():
  values.append('Passed' if x.Grades < 7 else 'Failed')
  df['Final_result'] = values
df
```

I'm getting 'tuple' object that has no attribute 'Grades'. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be good at pandas, avoid loops and start thinking "vectorized operations":

```py
import numpy as np

df["Final_result"] = np.where(df["Grades"] < 7, "Passed", "Failed")
```